# How to increment or decrement System Time using MFC or C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Is It possible to increment or decrement the system time ? If so, Please give your thoughts.

During my search, I can able to get the current system time and increment or decrement the time using `SYSTEMTIME` structure.

**EDIT**

In Linux, `gettimeofday()` function to get the current system time and `settimeofday()` function to set the system time given by the user.

Similarly, I need those two similar functions in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer for my question.

We can able to increment/decrement the system time in windows.

`GetSystemTime()` and `SetSystemTime()` functions are used to get the current system time and set the system time by the user.

**SAMPLE**

```
 SYSTEMTIME st;
 ::GetSystemTime(&st);
 st.wHour += 1;
 ::SetSystemTime(&st);
```